# Flutter, excluding a Dependency from iOS Build in Flutter (e.g., Stripe)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, stripe-payments, dependency-management

I am developing a Flutter application and have encountered a scenario where I need to include a specific dependency (in this case, Stripe) only for Android devices while excluding it from the iOS build. I have already implemented conditional logic using the `Platform` class to determine the platform, but it seems that the dependency is still being added to the iOS build, resulting in rejection from the App Store.

Here's an example of how I handled the conditional logic in my Flutter code:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Include Stripe-related functionality
  // Import Stripe package and use its features
} else {
  // Exclude Stripe-related functionality
}
```

Despite applying this approach, the dependency (Stripe) is still being included in the iOS build, causing compliance issues with the App Store guidelines regarding in-app purchases.

I am seeking guidance from the Flutter community on how I can prevent the inclusion of a specific dependency (e.g., Stripe) in the iOS build while ensuring it remains intact for Android devices. Are there any additional steps or configurations that need to be implemented to achieve this?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Note: Removing the dependency entirely from both platforms is not a viable option since it is crucial for our Android users.

Comment: When you add a flutter package, it usually supports both the platforms by default i.e. `Android` & `iOS` (others also, it available). From what I know, you cannot explicitly remove the dependency for iOS. You could try removing the dependency manually if it is added via `pods` but I doubt it will work. You could also add the android dependency to the Android project & manage that via a custom implementation using a `MethodChannel`.